# Google Takeout gives me corrupt zip files to download, would zip files corrupt based on browser choice?

Tags: zip, google-drive

I recently tried taking out large amounts of data from my google account, through Google Takeout. They have an option where you can download the files as .zip files (zip64) with a maximum of 50 GB each. With my files being over 200 GB, I downloaded around 5 split files with each being around 48 GB. However, upon trying to open them, every single zip extraction program I've used complains that the files are either incomplete or corrupt. Would anyone know what the problem might be?

Would the browser you chose to download the files with impact the validity of the zip files? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need a download manager for files over 250MB. Your ISP [or anyone else on the route from your data to you] is likely to start caching data... not always correctly.
Your browser *may* be to blame - it would be simple enough to test another - but a download manager will stand you in good stead for many things. Lots of them have plugins to intercept browser downloads, so you don't forget & get a broken file.

This is the advice section from an online service I use...
Personally, I've never tried their recommendation of ReGet - I'm on Mac & ReGet is Win-only software. As for PKZip - I've never had a broken zip file since I started using download managers

> Downloading large files over HTTP on the Internet can be tricky. To
> avoid the frustration of broken or corrupt downloads, observe the
> following suggestions when downloading from the Zip Manager:
> Never download any
> zip file or zip segment that is greater than 255 Megabytes (MB) in
> size. If your zip file is greater than 255 MB, use a download manager
> to split the download into multiple parts.
>
> This is a limitation of broken, or misconfigured, web cache servers
> operated by your ISP. These cache servers behave in unexpected ways
> when transferring files greater than 255 MB in size. They can induce
> corruption, or premature session termination.
>
> The cache servers are usually transparent. You can't tell they are in
> place until they corrupt a download.
>
> Use a download manager when ever possible. Avoid downloading large
> zips with your web browser. Configure your download manager to split
> your download into numerous parts. Make sure that each download
> segment is less than 255 MB. For example, if your zip file is 800 MB
> in size, you need to split the download into 4 parts. The download
> manager will automatically combine the parts into one whole file.
>
> Not only does using a download manager increase reliability of
> downloading large files over the Internet, they also increase your
> download speed.
>
> We recommend ReGet as a download manager. ReGet supports SSL as well.
>
> Do not try to resume a download on a different port then the download
> was started on. Your computer thinks that identical files on different
> ports are different files. If you switch ports, instead of resuming
> the file, your computer will start the download from the beginning.
>
> If you must use a web browser to download from the Zip Manager, make
> sure the browser's cache is set to at least twice the size of the
> largest zip file you plan to download. If you are using IE, make sure
> to check both checkboxes under Tools|Internet Options|Advanced|HTTP
> 1.1 settings. You will have to restart your browser for these changes to take effect.
>
> Make sure you have the newest firmware in your cable/dsl router. This
> is especially important for linksys routers. Older firmware versions
> contained incorrect MTU values that caused corruption at high speeds.
>
> If you are unlucky enough to get a corrupt or broken zip file, use
> PKZip to repair the zip and recover as many files as possible. PKZip
> has the best repair algorithms compared to other utilities.

Comment: Interesting, never understood what went on in the cache until now! I am on Mac, do you have any suggestions? If I wanted to download something from google drive, would I need to get into their API?

Comment: The best ever was Speed Download, now sadly gone. Best replacements I've found so far have been iGetter & Folx - neither are perfect. Try one at a time or their plugins will fight. They each install their own intercept plugin to browsers, so right click & DL with... or just click, depending on prefs.

Comment: I downloaded a 50GB zip file  from Chrome  web browser, the file was from google takeout, from a youtube channel I have, and it opened ok in Windows Explorer

Comment: @barlop - The site I got those instructions from have removed them sometime in the years since. These days, though I use JDownloader for most large downloads, except Backblaze & sometimes Mega, each of which have their own.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is absolute garbage. Your connection to Google Takeout is encrypted and neither your ISP nor any other intermediary can randomly cache the data. There aren't random spooky caches all over the web that cache stuff and thus corrupt your downloads. The only potential caches that may be in the way are CDNs, but they are set up by the website in question (that would be Google in this case) and not your ISP, but these CDNs are very seldom used for authenticated content.

Comment: @stefansundin - you're kind of missing the point that this answer & the attendant quote are from a time before https was standard & CDNs were rare. Browsers, however, can still to this day break over-sized downloads. Test something over 2GB from mega.nz from Safari  [which has a lower safe limit than Chrome] & it will warn you about it & suggest you use their own downloader. Personally, I use JDownloader for large files these days, if a service doesn't offer its own download structure.

Comment: At the time, if a download broke on the way, re-requesting it would fetch the same broken copy. Rebooting or changing browser would bypass the local ISP cache & have another go at fetching the original file.

Comment: Google had already started encrypting basically all of their network requests when Google Takeout launched in 2011. And the data that you export in Google Takeout is super sensitive so I really really doubt that they even considered providing that data unencrypted. Sorry but you should stop spreading these misconceptions.

Comment: @stefansundin - encryption really has nothing to do with it. You need to take a step back & analyse exactly which part of the transport layer you are dealing with.

Comment: So you are saying that a cache run by an ISP, that does not have Google's TLS encryption keys, are able to return a cached response to a network request that you issue to Google? This is not possible.

Comment: I'm so past arguing this point. It was perfectly acceptable to the OP 6 years ago. I doubt they care any more about why it happens… but it does.